# CSS Grid areas not giving equal width columns

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm playing around with CSS Grid a bit to learn a bit more about it. I'm creating a simple calculator. I'm using the `grid-template-areas` attribute to control where the buttons go. The issue is that the columns are not being distributed evenly across the width of the container. Here is the example:

[image]

Here is the CSS for the grid areas:

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
        'screen screen  screen   screen'
        'clear  clear   delete   divide'
        'seven  eight   nine     multiply'
        'four   five    six      subtract'
        'one    two     three    add'
        'zero   decimal negative equal';
    background-color: rgb(49, 55, 61);
    padding: 10px;
    grid-gap: 5px;
}
```

The corresponding elements have been assigned the correct grid areas. However as you can see in the image, the 9 button is much wider than the others, and the clear button is less than half the width of the screen, when it should be half.

As far as I understand it, using grid-template-areas with 4 columns should create an evenly distributed column/row that can then be used to place elements. Any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: you need to define the columns width: ex: grid-auto-columns:1fr

Comment: Ah perfect @TemaniAfif, thanks! I'll update with the answer.

Comment: don't update the question to include the answer, it need to remain a quesiton. The answer is already in the duplicate